# Facebook Instant Article error 403

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins

I recently implemented Instant Articles for WP Plugin on my Website. Everything works fine except for the download of the uploaded images.

Here is how the error looks like:

> General Errors: Could Not Download Image: Your image from URL http://www.theincentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/CnJ4p4WVYAAfC4O-575x337.jpg could not be downloaded with an error code 403. Please check to make sure image at http://www.theincentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/CnJ4p4WVYAAfC4O-575x337.jpg is active and loads correctly at that URL.

The image in the URL is accessible just not by the Instant Article. The result is that when the Article is published, the images are not loaded (They work fine on the website).

Comment: Hi @anh-nguyen-hoang did you found the solution for this issue? Thanks